# How to tell rsync not to delete some folders at destination?

Tags: rsync

So I use pelican for writing my blog and I upload the whole thing using rsync. OK.

But I use also Let's Encrypt and therefor need the repository .well-known preserved at the root of my website.

So is there a way I can say "rsync ... --do-not-delete .well-known ..."

Currently, those rep' are permission protected, but rsync doesn't like it.

Here is the current rsync command (installed by pelican itself, I did not write it) :

```
rsync -e "ssh -p $(SSH_PORT)" -P -rvzc --delete $(OUTPUTDIR)/ $(SSH_USER)@$(SSH_HOST):$(SSH_TARGET_DIR) --cvs-exclude
```

BTW : if you have also some suggestion to improve rsync efficiency, I take it (yes, it's off topic).

Comment: This stackoverflow answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438492/10452175

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From `man rsync`

> --delete
>         This  tells  rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving
>         side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but  only  for  the
>         directories  that  are  being synchronized.  You must have asked
>         rsync to send the whole directory (e.g. "dir" or "dir/") without
>         using  a  wildcard  for  the directory’s contents (e.g. "dir/*")
>         since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus  gets
>         a  request  to  transfer individual files, not the files’ parent
>         directory.  **Files that are excluded from the transfer  are  also
>         excluded from being deleted unless you use the --delete-excluded
>         option or mark the rules as only matching on  the  sending  side**
>         (see the include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES section).

So I think it should be

```
rsync -e "ssh -p $(SSH_PORT)" -P -rvzc --delete \
$(OUTPUTDIR)/ \
$(SSH_USER)@$(SSH_HOST):$(SSH_TARGET_DIR) \
--cvs-exclude --exclude=/.well-known
```

(assuming `.well-known` is at the root of `$(SSH_TARGET_DIR)/`)

Answer (score 14):

You should use the `--exclude` option in order to make `rsync` ignore that directory. Unless you also use `--delete-excluded` (which you shouldn't, in this case), it will leave it alone.